# Nvidia drivers not working with Fedora 22

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia

I used the net-installer package yesterday to install fedora 22 with the cinnamon desktop.  That installer was buggy but I eventually got it to do the install.  I then went to install my nvidia drivers.  First I tried the run file install and no matter what I did the driver kept detecting nouveau running on my system.  This was even after I did the minimal install and had not yet added any graphics or window managers.  I followed the following steps
to disable nouveau...

```
dracut --omit-drivers nouveau /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r) --force

systemctl disable gdm

reboot
```

These did not seem to do anything.

I gave up with the run file and decided to use the rpmfusion packages instead.  I installed the drive like this and it seemed to work.

```
sudo dnf install xorg-x11-drv-nvidia

sudo dnf install xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs.i686
```

This time it seemed to install well.  When I rebooted the system I made it to the login screen with no problem. However once I logged in cinnamon displayed some message about how it had crashed.  I then installed some other window managers and these would not open either.

I also tried installing the driver with a few other ways I found on the internet and all of the installs either did not work or caused it to crash in the same way.  I am using and Nvidia GTX 960 for my display along with a GTX 720 (no display just for debugging CUDA applications).  Does anyone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in this thread over at Fedora Forum and it worked great for me. http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=304646

I had applied the latest updates for F22 and used the latest NVIDIA drivers as of today (352.41).